# How do I fix MS access option group problem?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I created many option groups in MS Access 2013 and I am trying to populate my table according to what is selected in the option group. So, if the user selects option 1, I want "the text" not its value ex: "1" stored in my table. I tried the following code in AfterUpdate() event and it works fine:

```
Private Sub Frame49_AfterUpdate()
Dim D As Integer

 Select Case Me![Frame49]
  Case 1
      Me![Name] = "text"
    D = 1
  Case 2
    Me![Name] = "text1"
  D = 2
  Case 3
    Me![Name] = "text2"
  D = 3
  Case 4
    Me![Name] = "text3"
  D = 4
  Case 5
    Me![Name] = "text4"
  D = 5
End Select
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

Rem D = Frame49.Value
End Sub
```

but when the end user answers the first question and tries to answer the next question, all options of the previous question get selected. How do I fix this? 
Here is the file to see what I mean:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WjrAhXCnk961mxBuxS3RYqOUpPA_GsyL

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OptionGroup frame and associated buttons/checkboxes must have a number value. Therefore OptionGroup frame must be bound to a number type field. If you want controls to reflect selection in a text field, then need code to set UNBOUND OptionGroup frame with corresponding number value. In other words, convert saved text back to number value. Code would most likely need to be in form Current event. Something like:

```
Me.Frame49 = Switch([Name]="text",1, [Name]="text1",2, [Name]="text2",3, [Name]="text3",4, [Name]="text4",5)
```

Alternatively, save number value to number fields. Text equivalent is provided by labels on form. Use lookup tables to provide text equivalent on reports or calculate the equivalents with expressions in query or textboxes. An expression like:
`Choose([Name], "text", "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4")`

BTY, Choose() expression can be used in place of Case structure in your original code.
`Me![Name] = Choose(Me.Frame49, "text", "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4")`

Also recommend using radio (option) buttons instead of checkboxes.

Other alternatives are comboboxes and listboxes instead of option groups.

Advise not to use reserved words as names for anything. `Name` is a reserved word. Also, avoid spaces and punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, But I'm new to Access, can you please give me more info about how to set UNBOUND Option Group frame. or how to use lookup tables for text equivalent on reports or calculate the equivalents with expressions in query or textboxes.

Comment: Set UNBOUND Option Group frame with code that would be the reverse of what you have already posted. See edited answer. Lookup tables and calculations in query/textbox are both basic Access functionality. Have you even studied an introductory tutorial book?

Answer (score 0):

even though the option group only takes numeric values, you can achieve what you want by hard coding the values using if statements e.g

```
        If Frame5 = 1 Then orukolook = "okay"
        If Frame5 = 2 Then orukolook = "right"
        If Frame5 = 3 Then orukolook = "fine"
```

orukolook is the textbox control that you want the texts to be inserted, so if the first option of the option group is selected,the text "okay" will be inserted into the textbox control, if second option then the text "right" will be inserted.

The values hard coded in the place holder oruko look,e.g okay,right, fine  are the labels associated to each value in the option group.

Comment: Binding textbox to field will allow display of saved text but Option Group will not reflect selected value when navigating records. Maybe this is not important but I presume OP would like it to.

Answer (score 0):

Frame49 is bound to a database field.

When the user clicks a checkbox, the field's value (along with Frame49's value) is set to an integer.

You then change the database field's value to a string.

This causes Frame49's value to be set to that string.

Since that is an invalid value for an Option Group, all the related checkboxes show as a solid black square, representing an indeterminate state. That is not the same as a checkmark, so your observation "all options of the previous question get selected" is incorrect.

The simplest way to do what you want is to use a 1-column ListBox instead of an Option Group. You can size each ListBox so that it shows all the options as text strings.

When the user clicks an "option" to select it, the corresponding text string will be written to the database, with no VBA code involved.

When the user goes back to a previous record, the ListBoxes will all show the proper selections.

If you don't want to change how your form looks, then you must do as others suggested, and make Frame49 unbound, i.e. set its Control Source to blank.

Then when you set the database field's value to a text string, Frame49's value will remain as an integer.

If you want the ability to go back and edit earlier records, you can do it but it is beyond what I can answer here.